# Can't find element by CLASS_NAME SELENIUM

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to find element by class name `vc-day-content vc-focusable is-disabled`. I need onle by class name. I want to press available date in calendar. While trying to find calendar by class name, i've got success. But when i am trying to find element by class that locates in calendar I didn't find anything. I thought that reason is that one element is inside of other, but after trying to find one element in other - still nothing

How calendar looks like

[image: code of calendar]

How I am trying to find element by CLASS NAME `vc-day-content vc-focusable is-disabled`

```
calendar_container = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "vc-pane-container")
print('calendar_container - ', calendar_container)

first_month_search = calendar_container.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "vc-day-content vc-focusable is-disabled")
print('elements are - ', first_month_search)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selector, like below

```
first_month_search = calendar_container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="vc-day-content vc-focusable is-disabled"]')
```

Comment: There's no reason to make the class a strict string comparison in a CSS selector. It defeats so much of the flexibility of CSS selectors over XPath.  Use `span.vc-day-content.vc-focusable.is-disabled` instead.

Comment: @Ajeet Verma, it works. But i still can't understand why ```find by CLASS_NAME``` not working

Comment: @Alex, I guess it may be because the desired class is deeply nested inside your defined "calendar_container" parent element (which you can find directly by class name). Additionally, if the element with the desired class name is nested within another element, such as a <span> tag, find by class name method may not be able to find it directly. I may be wrong but this is what I think might be the reason. And, maybe you can try finding the "div" with class="vc-weeks" within your "calendar_container" first and then try finding your desired class by class name. It might work this way.